# Deriving the age process CDF from a renewal process

Tags: self-study, stochastic-processes

My question is whether I correctly derived the CDF of the steady-state age process. For context on why I' am asking this question is problem 6.1(a) from [Introduction to Stochastic Processes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/158488651X) by Lawler which I' am reading on my own. Here is the problem:

$\textbf{6.1}$ Suppose the lifetime of a component $T_i$ in hours is uniformly distributed on [100,200]. Components are replaced as soon as one fails and assume that this process has been going on long enough to reach equilibrium.

$\textbf{(a)}$ What is the probability that the current component has been in operation for at least 50 hours?

Here is what I think the answer should be in order to answer the question. The distribution function of $T_i$ is,
$$F(t)=\frac{t-100}{100}$$

Then according the Lawler, the distribution function of the steady-state age distribution is

\begin{align}
\psi_A(x)&=\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}P(A_t\leq x) \\
&=\frac{1}{\mu}\int_{0}^{x}[1-F(s)]ds \\
&=\frac{1}{150}\int_{0}^{x}\left[1-\frac{s-100}{100}\right]ds \\
&=\frac{1}{150}[2s\Big|_0^{x}-\frac{s^2}{200}\Big|_0^{x}] \\
&=\frac{1}{150}[2x-\frac{x^2}{200}]
\end{align}

The answer to the question would be $P(A\geq 50)=1-P(A\leq 50)=0.416$. But I do not think I derived the correct CDF for the age process. I say this because I would expect $\psi_A(200)=1$ because the maximum age is 200, however, using my derivation from above $\psi_A(200)=1.333$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $T_i \sim \mathcal{U}[100,200]$ then the
corresponding CDF is
$$ F(t) = \begin{cases} 0 & \mbox{ if } t<100 \\ \frac{t-100}{100} & \mbox{ if } t \in [100,200] \\ 1 & \mbox{ if } t >200\end{cases}.$$
Therefore, the steady-state age distribution is
$$ \psi_A(x) = \lim_{t \to \infty} P(A_t \leq x) = \frac{1}{\mu}\int_0^x (1-F(s))\mathrm{d}s= \begin{cases}\frac{x}{\mu} & \mbox{if } 0\leq x<100 \\ \frac{1}{\mu}\left(100 + \int_{100}^x\left(1-\frac{t-100}{100}\right) \mathrm{d}t \right) & \mbox{if } 100 \leq x< 200 \\ 1 & \mbox{if }  x\geq 200\end{cases}. $$
Now you should be able to find your answer.